# Facebook Like button shows strange dialog window

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I added the following Facebook Like code in my blog.
But when I clicked on the button, it showed up a small dialogue window which looks like this:
http://www.badongo.com/pic/13928565

I don't want this dialog window. I simply want the count of like button to increase.
Someone please help me, thanks!

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/zh_TW/all.js#appId=189257097820759&xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="imobile.tw" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="40" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Comment: Looks like there's a bunch of syntax errors to me, but can you edit the question with code that does not have the <?php echo code in it, and instead the actual URL? There's no way to test the code you posted without that. I would suggest looking up how to make a Facebook like button on Google and start from scratch. Also, when I've wanted to do the Like button with the +1 likes adding up, I think the only version that really worked out of the box was the iFrame option.

Comment: Thank you miahelf. I've edited the code with my URL in it.

Comment: Well, it didn't work when I added your code to an HTML file, but when I changed this line: js.src = "//connect.facebook... and added in http: before the // it worked fine with no flyout.

Answer (score 3):

In your CSS:

```
.fb_edge_comment_widget.fb_iframe_widget { display: none !important }
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these CSS workarounds seem to be working as of now (December 2012), so I advise you to use a more reliable solution: Simply place the fb:like into a div with `overflow: hidden`. If the div will be small enough (just to display the Like button), it will work.

Put this into your html file:

```
<div id="fbLikeContainer">
    <fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" width="70" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
</div>
```

And this into your CSS file:

```
#fbLikeContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you check the official [Like button reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)  on *Facebook developers*, particularly the section **When I click the Like button, the popup window (or "flyout") doesn't show. Why?**, you'll see that that's what Facebook suggests you to do (though unintentionally)

Answer (score 0):

After reading the Facebook developer page, I think the new style of a URL "Like" includes the flyout / dialog. You could possibly hide the flyout with a div around the Like button set to the correct size and with the overflow: hidden CSS property assigned to it. The other option is to use the Like button with Facebook pages. This is called the Like Box, but again, only works with Facebook pages / URLs. Perhaps you could create a Facebook page for your site and have all the Like buttons link to that?

Here is the Facebook Like Box generator, which you can turn off most of the features to get just the Like button and not all the extra stuff:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Here is the Facebook Like Button generator, that has a flyout also, and they mention the flyout might get hidden although don't talk about it as though you might *want* to hide it:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: I think the flyout was added to the Like button when they deprecated the Share button.

Comment: Nah, it was separate to that; I don't think it appears if there's no detected space to render it, i'm not sure what method is used to decide if there's space or not. If you're using the XFBML version it shouldn't popunder any other elements. The popup allows users to write comments about your link when sharing it to their wall, i think it increases clickthrough rates too, so i'm surprised you'd want to hide it