# Want to turn off the "flyout" pane in the Facebook like button.. any solution to this?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Why does Facebook not a have a flag to turn off the flyout pane in the Facebook like button?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005943/facebook-like-button-shows-strange-dialog-window (which has a simple CSS solution).

Answer (score 0):

Facebook say the XBFML has the flyout, maybe this means the Iframe doesn't.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

The Share-Me-Not extension for Firefox blocks those obnoxious flyouts.